# How do I disable a form without erasing/deleting it?

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I disable a form without erasing/deleting it?

Answer (score 2):

To disable a form without deleting it:

1. Go to Form Settings in your form builder.
2. Select the Limit Form Availability? option.
3. Set the Availability End date to any time in the past. Additionally, include a message to indicate that the form is no longer available.

[image]